# A measure-theoretic characterization of the empty set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This question relates to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822338/how-can-one-pass-from-almost-surely-to-surely).

> The question is about a (unambiguous) characterization of the empty
>   set in measure-theoretic terms.

In effect trying to formalize the notion that if the measure of a set is zero (by any appropriate measure one can apply) it should  be the empty set.

Is this correct and if so can this be formalized like this?

Comment: Are you saying $A\subset X$, $\mu(A)=0$ for **all** the measures on $X$ $\implies$ $A=\emptyset$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, yes this is what is asked if such an implication holds (for some formalization of appropriate measures on the set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the measure of a set $A\subset \Omega$ is zero under any sufficiently good measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$ (Lets say sufficiently good means probability measure or Radon measure), then $A=\emptyset$. However this is rather trivial, since you just need to check all dirac measures $\mu = \delta_x$ for all $x\in \Omega$.

On the other hand, if you disallow dirac measures or similiar measures, that give positive measure to a single point, you will always find zero sets that are not the empty set.

Or if you want a single measure, you need to take the counting measure $H^0$ (or some variant with weighting) which just is given by

$$H^0(A) = \mbox{ number of elements of $A$}.$$

However any such measure always $\infty$ for all uncountable sets like intervals and therefore in practice mostly useless.

Comment: +1, i like the answer since it answers the question *almost* in the positive. Indeed it breaks down to a formalization of *appropriate measures* for the given set

Comment: Is the first part of your answer a theorem that is published, or maybe you can add some more details?

Comment: Maybe another approach would be to use a series of (candidate) measures and get the characterization as a limit or fixed point of this series of *appropriate measures*?

Comment: There's no published theorem directly, just the basic idea that everythin hinges on whether or not you are able to "see" sets $\{x\}$ consisting of single points. If you "see" them, then you see all sets since they include such sets as subsets, if you don't, then you don't... However there is Lebesgue's decomposition theorem which is closely related, since it decomposes any measure into different parts, one of them being the discrete measure, which you need.

Comment: Great, this is eaxctly the point of the question, if one is able to measure a set as zero by any measure applicable, it should be the empty set. However i have the feeling this holds for finite (or maybe countable sets), is this also the case for un-countable sets? How would this relate to the linked question (feel free to answer there also if you like)

Comment: The answer is good. i will wait for other answer(s) or maybe this answer can be elaborated a little more (maybe using a set of measures or a limit of a sequence of measures). Trying to achieve maximum generality..

Answer (score 2):

**Counter example:**
Let $A=\{1\}$ be a non-empty set and say $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then:
$$\mu(\emptyset)=0$$
But also:
$$\mu(A)=0$$
So:
$$\mu(\emptyset)=\mu(A)$$
even tough $A\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: I do not think this is an answer to OP's question.

Comment: How does your answer holds against the other answer posted which answers almost in the positive? And why should $\mu(A)=0$ equal zero? Since this is a discrete set and not a continous one?

Comment: Note that i was using the Lebesgue measure, so from the definition it follows that $\mu(A)=0$ for given the given set $A$. But one can also use this argument if $A$ is a non-discrete set; the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is a common used example of an uncountable set where the Lebesgue measure is zero. But maybe I'm not answering your question right, because i'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'appropriate measures'?!

Comment: Counter-examples are of course correct. The question asks under what conditons (what measures) would allow to conclude that a measure-zero set is in fact the empty set (and not a counter-example)

Comment: So the question is: 'What measure implies that a null set is actually the empty set? And does such measure exist?' Then I would refer you to mlk's post, where he answers the stated question: the counting meausure. Even tough it's useless for measuring uncountable measures, you only want to measure the empty set with zero-measure and the non-empty sets as non-zero (this holds true for the counting measure).

Comment: Yes this can be an answer (maybe a trivial one), however what i was thinking (maybe i am wrong) is for a family (or set) of measures or maybe a sequence of measures, which as a set (or as a limit) when applied to a set and give zero result that set is indeed the empty set. This is an issue relevant (at least i think it is relevant) to Statistical Mechanics and Ergodic Theory

Comment: To elaborate a little more on this. If such a sequensce or set of measures can be formalized, then the ["measure-zero" problem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/statphys-statmech/#3) in statistical mechanics can re-formulated and possibly have a sense as to what kind of measures are "physical" in such contexts (for lack of better word)